# Tokenizer returning 1 more than expected, not sure what to add/remove

Tags: c++

> Errors:
>
> `NS_TOKEN_FREQ::getTokenFreqVec( const string& istr, vector<TokenFreq> & tfVec)`: can it handle a string of zero tokens?
>
> Test feedback
>
> :( The input string contains only white spaces, so the correct number of tokens identified should be: 0. Your function however identifies:1 tokens
>
> `NS_TOKEN_FREQ::getTokenFreqVec( const string& istr, vector<TokenFreq> & tfVec)`: can it handle a string of <=3 tokens? This unit test calls your overloaded operator<< to print out a TokenFreq object.
>
> Test feedback
>
> :( The input string :{aa bb aa bb   aa } contains 2 tokens, Your function however identifies:3 tokens

Function I use:

```cpp
void getTokenFreqVec(const string &istr, vector<NS_TOKEN_FREQ::TokenFreq> &tfVec) //possibly const in front of string
{
    string value;
    int flag;
    TokenFreq t;
    istringstream isStream(istr);
    while (getline(isStream, value, ' ')) 
    {
        transform(value.begin(), value.end(), value.begin(), ::tolower);
        flag = 1;
        for (long unsigned i = 0; i < tfVec.size(); i++) 
        { 
            if (tfVec[i].token == value) 
            {
                tfVec[i].freq += 1; 
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if (flag) 
        { 
            t.token = value;
            tfVec.push_back(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Header file used:

```cpp
struct TokenFreq
{
    std::string token;
    int freq = 0;
};
```

Comment: In `if (flag)` you need `t.freq = 1;`. (this will correct your `freq` count) Instead of `getline(isStream, value, ' ')`, you can simply use `isStream >> value`. Suggest `size_t` instead of `long unsigned` for loop variable. Then your code will find `tfVec.size() == 2` and `"3 - tok: aa"` and `"2 - tok: bb"`

Comment: The code shown does not produce the results quoted. It produces the correct number of tokens ([proof](https://ideone.com/JLvEtD)), just not the correct frequencies